# Search for a good analogy in the real world for the mathematical concept of set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I looked for a good explanation of a set for a course. Therefore I want to find a good analogy of this concept in real life. First I thought of explaining the set as something like a container such as a box. But a box has an identity regardless of its content, i.e. the box stays the same if its content changes. In contrast the identity of a set depends highly on its elements. If you add an object to a set you get a new one.

Second thoughts were something like a school class or a band. But also a school class remains the same if a new pupil joins the class during the year and band members can change.

Do you know a good analogy of a set in real life – some kind of collection which changes (or we think of it as to be a new collection) if its elements changes?

To explain the concept of sets I want to say: *"A set is something like ..."* And ... shall be something everyone knows from his everyday life.

Comment: Your analogy with the box is not wrong. The real point is that the set is *not* the box, but the *content* itself. So, when you remove a bottle of beer from your box, the box does not change, but its content (the amount of bottles) does. Think also to the empty set. An empty box is still a box, with its own "identity". Two empty boxes are different from each other. The empty set is the content of an empty box, so that two different empty boxes have the same content : the empty content.

Comment: What about a plastic bag like the one you get from supermarket? Of course, you have the same objection than for box, but in <i>real life</i>, no one really care about the bag itself, but only about its content. 

In Anvers in Belgium, they transport diamond in plastic bags. Do you think a bag containing diamonds is the same as the same bag containing your regular food shopping?

Comment: Your example about the school class shows us that when we "identify" it, we do not think of it as a *finite* list of members (the scoolboys) but as an "abstract" entity : class 3D of JF Kennedy lower school in city X.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I like the idea of explaining the set as "the content of a bag"... ;-)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: "the set is *not* the box, but the *content* itself." Might it be better to say that the set is BOTH the box and the content? My thinking is that $\{1,2,3\}\neq 1,2,3$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Mauro points in the comments, the analogy of the box is good, but you take it one step too far. The importance is not the box itself but rather its content. Sets are the mathematical realization of "the content of the bag", rather than the bag itself.

This means that in order to find a nice analogy you should probably look for something in the real world which is well-defined, but not bound by a physical object somehow. For example, families. Your immediate family (parents, siblings) is a well-defined concept. If someone had the same parents and the same siblings as you, then they have the same family. That is to say, if two families have the same members then it's the same family.

Answer (score 1):

You should think a set like a collection of things with a common property and the restriction that not all properties are allowed.For example, the set of numbers that are even. To be even is an allowed property. On the other hand, you should already know that $\{x∣x∉x\}$  is not a set, cause this property is not allowed. For more information, any text in basic set theory would be helpfull.

If you want an example in real world, we could say,the set of humans being mathematicians ,i.e. a set of things, people, satisfying certain property.

Comment: You probably mean something like $\{x\mid x\notin x\}$ is not allowed (Russell paradox)

Comment: Yes, edited, problems with latex hehe

Comment: Your example is good if I just concern the set of mathematicians at a special time. Over time this set changes. It would be great to find a sort of collection which remains the same over time...

Comment: If you believe in "destiny", the set of mathematicians remains the same hehe

Comment: @tampis: Sets change "over time" as well, only now over time might be "between models of set theory". The set of integers can change from one model to another, the set of real numbers can change from one model to another, and so on. Why would a real world analogy, which is *just* an analogy for chrissake, be constant and fixed?

Comment: @AsafKaragila good point...

Comment: @Lotus, yes given any deterministic model of the universe, the set of *all* mathematicians (i.e. across all times) is fixed and unchanging.

Comment: About "analogies", it useful to reflect on the historical origin of the "naive" concept of set (Dedekind, Cantor, Frege; see, by José Ferreirós, http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/settheory-early/ in *Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy*) and the interplay between "the notion of a collection [...] and logical ideas about classes". Roughly speaking, *classes* are "individuated" by a concepts, *collections* are "listed". A "nice" real-life example of sets and their property (i.e.inclusion) is showed by *army* : an army is a set of brigades, a brigade is a set of companies ... 1/2

Comment: ... a company is a set of platoons, a platoon is a set of soldiers (a soldier - in this analogy - is nor more a set : it is an *urelement*). But, as in the school example above, a platoon is "individuated" by the listing of its soldiers, or is an "abstract" entities that can exists independently of the soldiers belonging to it (that can be killed or transferred to other companies) ?

Answer (score 1):

Its not perfect, but: imagine you're cooking a stir fry.

A set is like an ingredient list; if you add or remove some items, it is not the same. On the other hand, if you merely change the order in which the ingredients are written, that's okay.